# Redrawing a page after a jquery append or after adding innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I'm adding validation to existing code. The view is loaded using ajax, because there are multiple tabs on the page. I got the validation itself to work, by returning a JSON object. The tab displayed depends on if the JSON object contains errors or not. If there are errors, a new page isn't loaded, and validation errors are displayed at the top of the page.

The problem is that the error messages push the page content down, but doesn't expand its containers (they don't have fixed heights), such that it extends beyond its container. I think it's because the entire page isn't redrawn, how do I fix this? I've tried using innerHTML instead of appending using jQuery, but it doesn't make a difference, the page is still distorted.

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: actionURL,
datatype: "json",
data: this.GetParams(),
success: function (data) {
if (data.Error) {
//$("#validationErrors").empty().append('<ul>');
//for(var i=0; i<data.ErrorMessages.length; i++) {
//$('#validationErrors').append('<li>' + data.ErrorMessages[i] + '</li>');
//}
//$("#validationErrors").append('</ul>');
document.getElementById('validationErrors').innerHTML = '<ul><li>Username is required</li></ul>'
}
else {
//load another page  
}
});
```

Comment: This sounds like a CSS problem.

Comment: Could we get a jsFiddle for this?  I'd make one myself, but I need your CSS and HTML to do that.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to get the height and add a constant to it. Not the solution I was looking for, but it works for now. I wonder if this is just an IE7 problem, haven't tried it in other browsers.

```
$('.container).height($('.container).height() + 1)
```